# Handlebars php (LightnCandy\LightnCandy) : each keyvalue pair NULL

Tags: null, each, keyvaluepair, mustache.php

I use [LightnCandy\LightnCandy](https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy) to template handlebars in PHP. I want to print some key/value pair on my template (if you have better, thanks to show me :) ).

I've try to get key value by :

- Classic method `{{#each my_table as |val key|}}`
- Testing method `{{#each my_table as |val|}}` and get the key by `@key`
- By `@index` / `@key` and `this` with `{{#each my_table}}`

My layout.hbs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <main role="main">
      {{> page}}
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

My my_page.hbs :

```
{{dump my_table}}
{{#each my_table as |val key|}}
<article role="article">
  @KEY [ {{dump @key}} ]
  @INDEX [ {{dump @index}} ]
  THIS [ {{dump this}} ]
  VAL [ {{dump val}} ]
  KEY [ {{dump key}} ]
</article>
{{/each}}
```

My PHP render:

```php
// Get HBS file first
$hbs_content = file_get_contents('my_page.hbs');
if(empty($hbs_content)) throw new \Exception('HBS file not found: "my_page.hbs"');

// Render temp file
$renderFile = 'render.php';

// Get layout file
$layout = file_get_contents('layout.hbs');
if(false===$layout) throw new \Exception('Cannot read layout file "'.$layout.'".');

// Compile layout with hbs_content
$pageContent = LightnCandy::compile($layout, array(
  'helpers' => array(
    'dump' => function($x) { return var_export($x, true); }
  ),
  'flags' => LightnCandy::FLAG_ELSE|LightnCandy::FLAG_ADVARNAME|LightnCandy::FLAG_SPVARS|LightnCandy::FLAG_ERROR_EXCEPTION,
  'partials' => array(
    'page' => $hbs_content
  )
));

// Save the compiled PHP code into a php file
if(!file_put_contents($renderFile, '<?php '.$pageContent.' ?>')) throw new \Exception('Cannot write render file.');

// Get the render function from the php file
$renderer = include($renderFile);

// Save content
echo $renderer(array(
  'my_table' => array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
  )
));
exit();
```

My HTML output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main role="main">
  array (
    &#039;key1&#039; =&gt; &#039;value1&#039;,
    &#039;key2&#039; =&gt; &#039;value2&#039;,
    &#039;key3&#039; =&gt; &#039;value3&#039;,
  )
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key1&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 0 ]
              THIS [ NULL ]
              VAL [ NULL ]
              KEY [ NULL ]
      </article>
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key2&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 1 ]
              THIS [ NULL ]
              VAL [ NULL ]
              KEY [ NULL ]
      </article>
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key3&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 2 ]
              THIS [ NULL ]
              VAL [ NULL ]
              KEY [ NULL ]
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main role="main">
  array (
    &#039;key1&#039; =&gt; &#039;value1&#039;,
    &#039;key2&#039; =&gt; &#039;value2&#039;,
    &#039;key3&#039; =&gt; &#039;value3&#039;,
  )
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key1&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 0 ]
              THIS [ value1 ]
              VAL [ value1 ]
              KEY [ key1 ]
      </article>
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key2&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 1 ]
              THIS [ value2 ]
              VAL [ value2 ]
              KEY [ key2 ]
      </article>
      <article role="article">
              @KEY [ &#039;key3&#039; ]
              @INDEX [ 2 ]
              THIS [ value3 ]
              VAL [ value3 ]
              KEY [ key3 ]
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I miss ?